# Overriding shovel method in rails in association case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

According to [the has_many documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many), the "shovel" method `collection<<(object, …)`

> Adds one or more objects to the collection by setting their foreign keys to the collection's primary key. **Note that this operation instantly fires update SQL without waiting for the save or update call on the parent object**, unless the parent object is a new record.

If you want to construct a new-record without saving it to the database just yet, use `collection.build`.

> Returns one or more new objects of the collection type that have been instantiated with attributes and linked to this object through a foreign key, but have not yet been saved.

Using Club and Member as example models:

```
club = Club.find(params[:id])
club.members.build(member_attributes) # member is not saved
club.save # saves club and members
```

**BUT WHAT IF**

I would like to use `<<` to create associations and not firing SQL at all. How can I override `<<` to behave like in scenario when the parent object is a new record?

Comment: what tags should I add to gain more attention ( read views )